# Consuming MassTransit+RabbitMQ messages in non .Net applications

Tags: java, android, rabbitmq, masstransit

I plan to implement the message bus where messages would be produced in .Net Core application but consumer applications are to be running on Android devices and written on Java. In initial approximation publisher application will know nothing about consumers. Java tablets will subscribe to message bus, receive messages and unsubscribe from bus. It looks like I'll need to dynamically create queue for each of the Android tablets, bind it to fanout exchange and send messages to the exchange or something like that. For .Net there is the MassTransit framework that already have all this stuff but I am not aware of Java and Android Studio capabilities. I am curious is there any way or a workaround to implement MassTransit consumer application on Java? I've been googling about 2 hours and didn't find any info but I assume that my search requests were incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

MassTransit uses JSON by default for messages, the structure of which is [documented on the web site](https://masstransit-project.com/architecture/interoperability.html). You can also send raw JSON messages if the envelope structure used by default is unnecessary.

As for how to consumer RabbitMQ messages from an Android device, I don't have any input there. Surely there is a client SDK.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for your answer! You got it right, client SDK for Android or article where similar case was described are the things I'm looking for. Unfortunately I didn't succeed so far.